# i am getting this error with tortoise-orm..ImportError: cannot import name 'TortoiseRouter' from 'tortoise

Tags: fastapi, tortoise-orm

```
Tortoise.init(
    db_url='sqlite:///path_to_my_db_file',
    modules={'models': ['main']},
    generate_schemas=True,
    add_exception_handlers=True,
    routers=[DatabaseRouter()]  
)

Tortoise.register_models(...)
```

This is the error i get.
from tortoise import Tortoise, TortoiseRouter
ImportError: cannot import name 'TortoiseRouter' from 'tortoise' (/Users/neo/.local/share/virtualenvs/joberman-mYfL6jQS/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tortoise/**init**.py)

Comment: Why would that work? There is no `TortoiseRouter ` in the `tortoise` library.